# Symfony2, Doctrine, add\insert\update best solution for big count of queries

Tags: php, symfony, optimization, doctrine-orm

Let's imagine we have this code:

```
while (true)
{
    foreach($array as $row)
    {
       $item = $em->getRepository('reponame')->findOneBy(array('filter'));

       if (!$item)
       {
           $needPersist = true;
           $item = new Item();
       }

       $item->setItemName()
       // and so on ...

       if ($needPersist)
       {
           $em->persist();
       }
    }
    $em->flush();
}
```

So, the point is that code will be executed a lot of times (while server won't die :) ). And we want to optimize it. Every time we:

1. Select already entry from repository.
2. If entry not exists, create it.
3. Set new (update) vars to it.
4. Apply actions (flush).

So question is - how to avoid unnecessary queries and optimize "check if entry is exist"? Because when there are 100-500 queries it's not so scary... But when it comes up to 1000-10000 for one while loop - it's too much.

PS: Each entry in DB is unique by several columns (not only by ID).

Comment: Your code is lacking some details - What data identifies an entry, if it's not just the id? Where does the data for the new entries come from? -, has some errors(?) - `findOneBy(array('filter'))` and `$item->setItemName()` - and why `while(true))`?

It seems like your query only persists new items. Do some existing items need to be updated as well? If your entries are not just identified by id, what columns is your primary key composed of. That sounds pretty much like the starting point for any optimization.

Comment: while(true) - to show that it can be looped from 1 to 1 million (this  is general example) data comes from agruments in function. yes but point is not in errors, i check it before call this code. table have 4-5 columns (i don't think that there is matter how much of it). yes, code is "update existing and if not addd new". now primary is id + action (string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of fetching results one-by-one, load all results with one query.

Eg.
let's say your filter wants to load ids 1, 2, 10. So QB would be something like:

```
$allResults = ...
    ->where("o.id IN (:ids)")->setParameter("ids", $ids) 
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResults() ;
```

1. "foreach" of these results, do your job of updating them and flushing
2. While doing that loop, save ids of those fetched objects in new array
3. Compare that array with original one using array_diff. Now you have ids that were not fetched the first time
4. Rinse and repeat :)
5. And don't forget $em->clear() to free memory

While this can still be slow when working with 10.000 records (dunno, never tested), it will be much faster to have 2 big queries than 10.000 small ones.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if you need them to persist or not after the update, retrieving 10k+ and up entries from the database and hydrating them to php objects is going to need too much memory. In such cases you should better fallback to the [Doctrine DBAL Layer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html) and fire pure SQL queries.

Comment: While this would improve performance, I argue against it, since Symfony promotes an object oriented approach and using dbal and arrays at least to me feels wrong. Imo a better solution would be to defer these tasks and detach them from the actual request using a JobQueue/worker or something like that. This way you can keep all the symfony-goodness of (hopefully tested) models/entities, validation, DI, etc. without having to resort to crude hacks. Please think about the poor soul which might have to sift through your "optimized" scripts to find a bug or change some sql ;)

Comment: Im doing this in my actual projects. All in the symfony framework (as a console command), but with dbal. Although the cli can run unlimited time, with millions of database entries, doctrine orm/odm will eat all your memory and get stuck. And this on a machine with GB RAM.